# cant able to add data to firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to add data to `Firebase` but data is not added to `Firebase` here is my code?

```
@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = self.addWeight.text{
        if let date = self.addDate.text{
            self.saveTaskWithName(name: text, date: date, completionHandler: { (success) in
                // data save successfully
                print("**** TASK ADDED *******")
            })
        }
    }
}

func saveTaskWithName(name:String,date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
        let dict = ["weight": name, "date" : date] as [String : Any]
        if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
            self.ref.child("WeightTracker/\(userid)").childByAutoId().setValue(dict) { (error, reference) in

                if let err = error{
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                    // data save successfully
                    completionHandler(true)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error, if so include it in the question, or how do you know it's not added?

Comment: i checked  in firebase console data is not adding

Comment: And no error? Try to print error object and not localizedDescription. `print(err)`

Comment: Please replace with my answer and try..

Comment: Do you want that data stored within a child within the user id? So the path would be *root_ref/WeightTracker/uid/auto_id_child/weight: xxxx* and also within the *auto_id_child/date: yyyy*

Comment: @ronakjani is below code works for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try below solution**

```
func saveTaskWithName(name:String,date:String, completionHandler:@escaping ((_ success:Bool)->Void)){
        let dataBaseRef = Database.database().reference()

        let dict = ["weight": name, "date" : date] as [String : Any]
        if let userid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid{
            dataBaseRef.child("WeightTracker").child(userid).setValue(dict) { (error, reference) in
                if let err = error{
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }else{
                    // data save successfully
                    completionHandler(true)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```